# Schema name duplication in EF6 code first migration

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Update-Database is outputting this error.

```
Table 'external_service.external_service.products' doesn't exist
```

Here is some Update-Database -Verbose output.

```
Target database is: 'external_service' (DataSource: something,     Provider: MySql.Data.MySqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [201503091803430_1.0.1].
Applying explicit migration: 201503091803430_1.0.1.
alter table `external_service.products` drop column `test`
```

This is what the db migration looks like...

```
public partial class _101 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropColumn("external_service.products", "test");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("external_service.products", "test", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
    }
}
```

Here is the POCO

```
// Both of these generate the same thing. :/
//[Table("external_service.products")]
//[Table("products", Schema = "external_service")]
[Table("products")]
public partial class Product
{
    [Column("productid")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long ProductID { get; set; }

    [Column("visible")]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Migration configuration

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SoundDevices.DataAccessLayer.Context.ExternalServiceContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\ExternalService";
    }

    protected override void Seed(SoundDevices.DataAccessLayer.Context.ExternalServiceContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm using EF 6.1.2 with MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.6 & MySql.Data 6.9.6

If I manually remove the "external_service" from the DbMigration, it works, but that seems incorrect. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on what your naming is meant to be.  If your database name is external_service and you want the table to be called products, specify:

```
[Table("products")]
```

This would create a table with the fully qualified name `external_service.products`.  In SQL server, this would be `external_service.dbo.products` (or `external_service..products`, as dbo is the name of the default schema.

If you were actually trying to create a table products in a schema called external_service within your database, also called external_service, then you would use

```
[Table("products", Schema = "external_Service")]
```

This would create a fully-qualified table name of `external_service.external_service.products`.

You've also mentioned that after you changed something and recreated your migration, it tried to rename or move a table.  This indicates that when creating your initial migration, you've not removed the older version.  To recreate your initial migration, undo the first one then recreate the new one:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:0
Add-Migration 1.0.1 -Force
```

Comment: Looks like external_service might be your database name.  If so, use `[Table("products")]` instead.

Comment: When I do that it generates "MoveTable(name: "external_service.products", newSchema: "dbo");", looks like it's trying to use a schema named dbo as a default?

Comment: Is this your first migration?  If so, sounds like you applied the first version of it and then changed it - roll back to the start and try to add the migration again.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to setup an existing database using this as a guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398.aspx

Comment: I removed the external_service from the table name headers, and generated it from scratch. It put dbo.product etc in the migration object, but when pushed to the database it updated correctly???

Comment: Updated answer with some explanations.

Comment: You mentioned SQL server, when I'm using MySQL. I wonder if there is some workflow difference that was causing my issue? The name should of been "servername.external_service.products", but I've never seen the server name specified in MySQL... Regardless, it appears fixed it by just omitting the schema name and recreating the tables from scratch. (They had no data anyways) I've added and removed a few fields with no problems.